# What is the second argument in antd select onChange function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, react-hook-form

Hey I have container component which passes the onChange event down to the AntD select input. I would like to pass it down and use in input.

I don't what to put in second parameter the type look like this

```js
var onChange: ((value: string | undefined, option: OptionsType | OptionData | OptionGroupData) => void) | undefined
```

Container looks like this

```
export const TagsInputContainer = ({ value, onChange }: ContainerProps) => {
  const { loading, payload, error } = useQuery(fetchTags({ perPage: PER_PAGE }));
  console.log('value in Container', value);

  const handleChange = (value: any) => {
    console.log('handleChange value', value);
    if (value) {
      setInputValue(value);
      onChange(value);
    }
  };

  return <TagsInput loading={loading} error={error} tags={payload?.results} onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

And input

```js
export const TagsInput = ({ tags, onChange }: Props) => {
  const { Option } = Select;
  let children: Array<ReactNode> = [];
  if (tags) {
    children = tags.map((tag: { tag: string }, idx: number) => {
      return (
        <Option value={tag.tag} key={idx}>
          {tag.tag}
        </Option>
      );
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <Styled.TagsSelect
      placeholder="Dodaj tagi"
      mode="tags"
      onChange={onChange}
      maxTagTextLength={INPUT_VALIDATE.tagCharMax}
    >
      {children}
    </Styled.TagsSelect>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter will be passed the **full option object** that was selected by the user.

The first parameter will receive just the **value** of the option, which is usually the thing you want. But sometimes you might want access to all the props which were set in the option, not just the value. And in that case you can use the second argument in your onChange handler.

The use of the second argument is optional. There is no need for you "put something" in there, you can just ignore it if you want.

For example, if the option that was selected looks like this:

```
<Select.Option key={1} value={3}>
    Foobar
</Select.Option>
```

...the call from AntD to your onChange handler will be:

```
onChange( 3, {key: 1, value: 3, children: 'Foobar'} )
```